# Can i define bootstrap "rows" to my Html.EditorFor

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, razor, html-helper, editorfor

I have updated my asp.net mvc5.0 to use asp.net mvc5.2.2, to be able to pass html attribute to `Html.Editorfor`. now i have this inside my razor view:-

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.SecondaryRole, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" , @rows="3"} })
```

i can get the effect for the form-control , but seems the rows=3 does not have any effect. i am usng rows=3 to have my editorfor display a textbox . here is the result from my above code:-

[image]

Comment: 1. `rows` on an editorfor doesn't make sense. 2. `rows` on a textbox (input) is not valid html

Comment: @Shoe  you mean i need to use rows with TextArea only ?

Comment: Yes that's correct. Use `style="height:100px;" to put height on an input.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
[DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
public string Text { get; set; }
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.datatype(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Can you add a bit more description to your answer?